# Looking to mimic the iPhone lock screen camera drag

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, drag

I've been searching and searching on how apple makes the dragging motion on the lock screen to open the camera so clean. I'm trying to do a similar thing with an app where you drag from the bottom up to reveal a menu, but i cant quite get it right. Anyone know how to, or of any tutorials that show how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can put a view above another and allow the user to drag it up. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up what's been mentioned by Hejazi I believe you can achieve this in 3 steps:

- create a background rectangle with some corner radius (this is a property of CGRect).
- create a top view, corresponding to the part you want to be able to slide. Attach a pan gesture to this view so you will be able to handle the animation for this view.
- for the text part being highlighted I think you need another two views: I will apply a mask corresponding to the text to a view so you get some transparency only for the letters of your text and animate a white round view behind it.

Comment: makes sense but i have no idea how to go about that